# Non-Type template argument: Implicit casting from bool to int works, but from double to int doesn't. Why is that?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

Reading about Non-Type template arguments, I stumbled upon [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/template_non-type_arguments.htm) article. In their example they define the class template `Myfilebuf` as follows:

```
template<class T, int size> class Myfilebuf
{
      T* filepos;
      static int array[size];
public:
      Myfilebuf() { /* ... */ }
      ~Myfilebuf()=default; // I made little changes here, to make the code compilable.
};
```

In the following they use this class template in an example, to explain which calls of this template class are possible and which ones aren't. The examples they give are the following:

```
Myfilebuf<double, (75>25)> x;       // valid
Myfilebuf<double,200.0> y;          // error, 200.0 is a double, not an int
```

So now I was wondering, since (75>25) is `bool` and not `int` either. I tried the code and it works (see [here](https://ideone.com/Dr6XQO)), so an implicit cast from `bool` to `int` is possible here, but not from `double` to `int`.
After seeing this behaviour I tried those castings without templates and they both work fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int anInt;
    bool aBool=true;
    double aDouble=0.;
    anInt=aBool;
    std::cout<<anInt<<"\n";
    anInt=aDouble;
    std::cout<<anInt<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm struggling to understand this behaviour. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: I suspect because going from double to int is a loss of precision, but bool to int is fine

Comment: You can look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion expecifically on Numeric promotions: _prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value._

Comment: @Amadeus Ok, I got it, thanks. Template arguments are not listed as prvalues here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue though. Are they prvalues nevertheless?